# Differentiate output based on people names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on this code that basically gives output based on the input (the users names) that the user give, i need help/ advice on how i can differentiate the output given based on the name.

i've tried if statements, but its really basic detecting, since i've only studied python not so long ago.

```
# var
import random

nopes = ("nope1", "nope2", "nope3")

list1 = 1

list2 = 2

list3 = 3

list4 = 4

list5 = 5

list6 = 6

list7 = 7

list8 = 8

list9 = 9


# functions
def mainfunc():

    if a in "name1":
        print(list1)
    elif a in "name2":
        print(list2)
    elif a in "name3":
        print(list3)
    elif a in "name4":
        print(list4)
    elif a in "name5":
        print(list5)
    elif a in "name6":
        print(list6)
    elif a in "name7":
        print(list7)
    elif a in "name8":
        print(list8)
    elif a in "name9":
        print(list9)
    else:
        talk()
def talk():

    print(random.choice(nopes))

#syntax's
a = input("What's your name? : ")

mainfunc()
```

yes, it works. but with a single typo the code would not work as i expected, and im trying to avoid that.

Comment: You are not expected to force do a "typo". Typo does make any working code not work. Going forward, you will learn about data structures that can store multiple values in one variable like list, tuple, etc. The most apt data structure here would be dictionary.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i'm really really sorry for the confusion, this is my first post here. To simplify, what i want to do is ask for input from the user and if their name is in my code, there will be a special output for them.

Comment: Can you provide a list of sample inputs? And what will be the sample outputs for those @teslaa

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely get the intention of your code, but if you want to print differnt lists based on the input, you could use a dictionary instead of the several `list#`-objects.

```
lists = {
  "name1": ["a","b","c"],
  "name2": ["d","e","f"]
}

a = "name1"

if (a in lists.keys()):
  print(lists[a])

# Output: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

That way, you just have to maintain the dictionary object and not many single objects and the elseifs

Comment: thanks for the tip! im really sorry for the confusion considering my intentions of the code. To simplify, what i want to do is print out a line of words based on the name that the user inputted in. For example, if the user name is stacy, she will get a unique output only for the name stacy itself. Other names will recieve different output. Again, im sorrry for the confusion.